# How to get row count with a query using Propel 1.6's Custom SQL?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, propel, symfony-2.1

I have a project in Symfony2 using Propel ORM 1.6 and PostgreSQL. I'm trying to get the number of rows from a Query [using Custom SQL as shown in this link](http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/03-basic-crud.html) in the following way:

```
$con = Propel::getConnection(VerbNounPeer::DATABASE_NAME);
$countSql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ("
               ." SELECT DISTINCT ON (fk_noun_id) *"
               ." FROM verb_noun"
               ." ORDER BY fk_noun_id, verb_noun_vote_count DESC"
               .") inner_tb";
$countSqlStmt = $con->prepare($countSql);
$countSqlStmt->execute();
```

The above query works fine. However, how do I get the integer value of the row count from the stmt (the above $countSqlStmt) object?
I tried using:

```
$recordsCount = $countSqlStmt[0];
```

However, given that $countSqlStmt is an object and not an array I get "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DebugPDOStatement as array..."

I also tried to convert it to an array using Propel's formatter:

```
$countSqlFormatter = new PropelArrayFormatter();
$countSqlRow = $countSqlFormatter->format($countSqlStmt);
```

However, this does not work either as I need to specify a criteria for the array, and I don't know what to put since my query result is just a row with a count value and not a class. If it were a class I would use:

```
$formatter->setClass('VendorName\NameBundle\Model\VerbNoun');
```

Any ideas? In [this link there is a use of PropelArrayFormatter()](http://trac.propelorm.org/browser/branches/1.5/test/testsuite/runtime/formatter/PropelArrayFormatterTest.php?rev=1371) but it was not of much help to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the data out of a PDOStatement, you have to call the [`fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#example-997) method on it.

Comment: Thank you K-Phoen! That was actually what was missing! I guess it was quite basic after all... 
The following works:
$countSqlStmt = $con->prepare($countSql);
$countSqlStmt->execute();
$countArray = $countSqlStmt->fetch();
$recordsCount = $countSqlStmt[0];